# Why this error from urllib?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urllib2

I get a strange error when using urllib:

```
INFO     2011-12-07 07:02:45,101 main.py:884] urlhttp://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=59.3333,18.05&sensor=false
WARNING  2011-12-07 07:02:45,103 urlfetch_stub.py:428] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['Host']
ERROR    2011-12-07 07:02:45,210 main.py:346] HTTPResponse instance has no attribute 'readline': 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/Lexar/montao/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/Lexar/montao/montaoproject/main.py", line 885, in get
    jsondata = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 391, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1185, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1176, in do_open
    resp = addinfourl(fp, r.msg, req.get_full_url())
  File "/media/Lexar/montao/google/appengine/dist27/urllib.py", line 978, in __init__
    addbase.__init__(self, fp)
  File "/media/Lexar/montao/google/appengine/dist27/urllib.py", line 926, in __init__
    self.readline = self.fp.readline
AttributeError: HTTPResponse instance has no attribute 'readline'
```

The code that used to work is

```
  url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json' + \
    '?latlng={},{}&sensor=false'.format(entity.geopt.lat, entity.geopt.lon)
  logging.info('url%s' % url)
  jsondata = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
```

Could you tell me what's wrong here? I read somewhere that the response object does not have a "get" method then how come it used to work? I think the difference is that I upgraded from SDK 1.6 to 1.6.1 pre-release. There might be some other difference between the code that is working and what is generating the error message.

Thank you

### Update

As stated in the answer, the following use of urlfetch works instead:

```
  url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json' + \
    '?latlng={},{}&sensor=false'.format(entity.geopt.lat, entity.geopt.lon)
  logging.info('url%s' % url)

  from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
  result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
  jsondata = json.loads(result.content)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with the SDK. I was able to replicate the exact same behavior. Is there any reason you are using `urllib2` instead of `urllib`?

Using Python2.7 and SDK 1.6.1, I tested the following:

```
import urllib  
url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json' + \
        '?latlng={},{}&sensor=false'.format(entity.geopt.lat, entity.geopt.lon)
logging.info('url%s' % url)
jsondata = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
```

and it worked as expected.

I'll follow up/file a bug if I can determine what's causing the file read error.

NOTE: I tested the code suggested by KJuly and it failed with the same error. It seems `urllib2` is relying on `urllib` when it shouldn't be. Digging further.

EDIT: Since `urllib` and `urllib2` are just wrappers for `urlfetch`, I might also suggest the following:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
jsondata = json.loads(result.content)
```

Second EDIT: In either case, we are using a local version of (`/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py`) of `urllib2`, which then tries to interact with a GAE specific version of `urllib` (`google/appengine/dist27/urllib.py`).

Comment: That's very interesting. I'll try all of this. Thanks you for your observations and for taking your time with my problem

Comment: Mum..It's weird. I get the correct result like my screenshot shown below. My python version is 2.7.2. :? And yeah, `urlfetch` is cool!

Answer (score 2):

Lose `Request()` method? Maybe it will works.

```
headers = { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' } // Maybe 'application/xml'
data = None
req  = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)    
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)         
data = resp.read()
jsondata = json.load(data)
```

I tried in python console:

> `>>>` import urllib2
>   `>>>` headers = { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' }
>   `>>>` data = None
>   `>>>` req = urllib2.Request("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=59.3333,18.05&sensor=false", data, headers)
>   `>>>` response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
>   `>>>` data = response.read()
>   `>>>` data

and it'll print the data correctly. Here is my result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you but I still get the error message when trying this answer. I don't really understand why.

Comment: @Nicke I've edited. Pay attention on `req  = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)`. :p

Comment: Thank you @Kjuly for the help. After editing I still get the same error message. This is local `dev_appserver`. I can try deploying it to production where I as of latst version don't have this error and see what the actual difference is, if the difference really is what I think it is ie switching from SDK 1.6 to pre-release 1.6.1 which appears unrelated. Thanks again for helping here.